# Angular Nebular nbInput - Add mask into input fields

Tags: angular, nebular, ngx-mask

I need to add mask into input text fields (phone, date, email, etc).

I'm using Angular and [Nebular 5.0.0](https://akveo.github.io/nebular/), and according to the [official documentation](https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/components/input/api#nbinputdirective), there is no mask attribute available.

I had tried to add [ngx-mask-version(8.1.7)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-mask) as follow, but doesn't worked.

```js
<input type="text" nbInput mask="(00)00000-0000" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="model.phone" name="phone">
```

Is possible to integrate ngx-mask and Nebular nbInput components? If is not possible, how can I add mask into my input fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved, the problem was in my environment.
I need to delete node_modules folder and build the project again.